# REST slug localization. Should I put translations into the slug?

Tags: rest

Should my restful URLs look like this:

http://example.com/en/city/Boston

http://example.com/de/stadt/Boston

or like this:

http://example.com/en/city/Boston

http://example.com/de/city/Boston

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rule often advocated for a REST API is that every resource should have exactly one URI, and that HTTP headers should be used to negotiate how it is to be accessed or manipulated.  There is, however, some room for debate about exactly how you determine what constitutes a distinct resource, and what is merely a different representation of that resource

In your example it could be argued that each city is a resource, but the translations of data about that city are a representation. This would suggest that the URL should always be `http://example.com/city/boston`, with the locale selected using an HTTP `Accept-Language` header.

An alternative interpretation is that you are actually presenting multiple APIs, each localised in their entirety - so `http://example.com/en/` is the base URL for an English API, and `http://example.com/de/` is the base URL for a German API which happens to provide similar access to the same resources. This then implies that the two APIs needn't be kept in sync, and can be tailored to their intended audience; specifically, it would suggest `http://example.com/de/stadt/Boston` was the better URL within the German API.

Bear in mind also that the names of resources themselves may have localised equivalents, not just resource types like "city" - so if cities were indeed your resource type, `http://example.com/en/city/Vienna` would correspond to `http://example.com/de/stadt/Wien`. This is neatly human-readable, but might be tricky to build into the underlying data model.

If your intention is simply to present the same content in as many languages as possible, then removing the locale from the URL entirely and relying on content negotiation via  `Accept-Language` would seem the more "RESTful" solution. If you specifically have a separate English and German market, which may not require the same content and functionality, then localising the URLs would seem to make sense.

Comment: If you accept the fact that a resource should only have one URI that returns a 200, then it becomes easy to distinguish what is a resource vs a representation.  A distinct URI that returns a 200 always points to a distinct resource.  Therefore `/city/boston` and `/en/city/boston` and `/de/stadt/boston` are three different resources.  It is only by using server driven conneg can a resource provide different representations for the same resource.

Comment: @DarrelMiller That is a good *post facto* definition of what *is* a resource, but when designing the API, you have to decide what *should be* a resource. If you create a URL like `/de/stadt/boston`, you are asserting that in your data model it is a distinct resource from `/en/city/boston`; the question becomes whether that is the right data model...

Comment: Agreed. I still find it a useful definition that helps to prevent people falling into the resource equals domain entity trap.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a RESTful URL.  Both sets of URIs are completely valid.  Pick whichever is easier for your server side framework to handle.  My guess is that would be the second.

Comment: Is this valid as well:

http://example.com/city/Boston and


http://example.com/stadt/Boston?

Comment: @lewicki Against what standard are you expecting "valid" to be judged? As to whether that is *wise*, I would say no - if you try to guess the language by their word for "city", you will have problems when two languages use the same word.

Comment: @lewicki  Both are valid URIs, REST has no opinion on what your URIs look like.  I suspect you may be asking some other design question that is implied by your URI structure, but I don't want to try and guess what that is.

Answer (score 0):

For server-side caching, and for intermediate or proxy caches, they might only look at the URI and maybe some of the *response* headers, but ignore other headers like the *request* `Accept-Language` header. For this reason, it is important to keep anything that modifies the response in the path or the query string of the URI. Both options are unique, so they both work in case the next HTTP request for "Boston" is in a different language - it will not be returned from a cache in the wrong language.

The first option has the advantage when it comes to SEO, but it can be challenging to determine the type of resource since the entire path is dynamic. You might process routes by grabbing the second part (e.g., "city" or "stadt") and then translate it to the default language to determine the resource "type" and process it further.

You might also want to include noindex and/or nofollow for modifiers in the URI that just sort or filter results and cause duplicate content.